# Flutter getting error declaring Future variable and giving it a return value of method

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

i'm trying to get summoner data from riot api, so i searched on youtube and did the same with the professional dude in the video. but when i try to declare a future variable and give it the return value, i get error saying 'Non-nullable instance field must be initialized.'. if anyone knows about this, please help me. TT I'm using android studio on m1 mac.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

const apiKey = '***'; // i put my api key here.
const summonerName = '길가네국밥단골';
const summonerInfoUrl =
    'https://kr.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/';

class SummonerInfoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value;
  SummonerInfoScreen(this.value);
  @override
  _SummonerInfoScreenState createState() => _SummonerInfoScreenState();
}

class _SummonerInfoScreenState extends State<SummonerInfoScreen> {
  Future summonerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    summonerFuture = getData(widget.value);
  }

  Future getData(String value) async {
    http.Response response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('$summonerInfoUrl$summonerName?api_key=$apiKey'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      var decodeData = jsonDecode(data);
      // summonerName = decodeData['name'];
      // summonerLevel = decodeData['summonerLevel'];
      // summonerProfileIcon = decodeData['profileIconId'];
      return decodeData;
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      return Text('error occured');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 75.0,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(),
              ),
              Text("소환사 이름: ${widget.value}"),
              Text("레벨: SummonerLevel"),
              SizedBox(
                height: 60.0,
              ),
              FutureBuilder(
                future: summonerFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data == null) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Center(child: Text("loading,,,")),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Text(snapshot.data['id']);
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize `summonerFuture`. Just call getData method in future.

```
future: getData(widget.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will go ahead of my self and assume you are using Null Saftey (got that from your error message).
Just add late keyword to your Future declaration, just like that:

late Future summonerFuture;

In case you are wondring what is late, it is a new keyword introduced with null saftey and it is job is to delay the initialisation of the variable.
If you are intrested  in knowing more about null saftey, check this video

https://youtu.be/HdKwuHQvArY

Sorry for the format, wrote it on my phone.